# How to protect webmin via .htpasswd?

Tags: apache-http-server, perl, webmin

Originally asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658240/how-to-protect-webmin-via-htpasswd) but I think it was the wrong site.

I have got webmin installed on my Ubuntu. What would be the best way of adding an additional password layer like via `.htpasswd` file?

So far I have tried placing `.htaccess` & `.htpasswd` in /etc/webmin folder but it doesn't seem to be picking up from there.

Comment: Webmin is self-hosted. It does not use Apache httpd. If you feel Webmin is insecure, don’t use it.

Comment: @DanielB By self-hosted, I think you mean has it's own server. That's actually quite helpful. It's not about what I 'feel', just don't think there's any need to expose a powerful tool to attacks. I might use it's restrict access to IPs feature.

Answer (score 0):

As comments replied, Webmin doesn't use Apache but miniserv, so creating a `.htpasswd` will not have the intended effect.

If you use Cloudflare, you can protect Webmin page(s) with a CF worker emulating a htpasswd behavior. See https://www.maxivanov.io/how-to-password-protect-your-website-with-cloudflare-workers/

I also agree that regardless of feelings, it's worth adding an extra layer of security if your webmin auth page is public. Webmin (< 2.0) had a severe vulnerability with password resets (https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-358/Webmin.html). Webmin (> 2.0) shows unwanted behavior in the auth process, like sending "Login to Webmin failed" notifications when it succeeded.